# How to change image directory in spatie media library?

Tags: laravel, laravel-medialibrary

I'm new to this package since I usually use the image intervention. So the problem is whenever I save an image, it is saving in storage directory instead of in public directory. I tried to review the documentation and did some research and didn't see any answer. Please see my code below for saving.

```
$user->addMediaFromRequest('avatar')->toMediaCollection('avatars');
```

Package:

https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v7/introduction

Comment: you need to make your own class extending default PathGenerator, read https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v7/advanced-usage/using-a-custom-directory-structure section

Comment: @AlzafanChristian Can you add an example and more details? The documentation is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Jonjie I would not recommend saving the images in the `/public` directory, instead save them in the  `storage/app/public` directory and create a symlink from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`, as explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk).

Comment: @Remul I appreciate your recommendation. But may I know the reason why?

Answer (score 7):

you can simply define the filesystem config with `$user->addMediaFromRequest('avatar')->toMediaCollection('avatars', 'disk');`

here is how im using the package(simple usage), if you need it later

on my model:

```
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMediaTrait;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\Models\Media;
class User extends Model implements HasMedia
{
use HasMediaTrait;
public function registerMediaCollections()
{
    $this
    ->addMediaCollection('avatar')
    ->singleFile()
    ->useDisk('public');
    ->useFallbackUrl(asset('/images/default-user.png'))
    ->useFallbackPath(public_path('/images/default-user.png'));
}

public function registerMediaConversions(Media $media = null)
{
    $this->addMediaConversion('avatar-thumb')->width(120)->height(120);
}
...
```

to get the file-url im using model accessor, added this function in my model:

```
public function getAvatarAttribute()
{
    $file = $this->getMedia('avatar')->first();

    if($file) {
      $file->url = $file->getUrl();
      $file->thumbnail = $file->getUrl('avatar-thumb'));
      $file->alternate = $file->getCustomProperty('alternate') ?: $file->file_name;
    }else{
      $file = new \StdClass;
      $file->url = $this->getFallbackMediaUrl('avatar');
      $file->thumbnail = public_path('/images/default-user-thumb.png');
      $file->alternate = 'avatar.png';
    }

    return $file;
}
```

also using custom path, in config\medialibrary.php set this array `'path_generator' => Path\To\Your\Class::class,`

then the class :

```
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\Models\Media;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\PathGenerator\PathGenerator as PathGenerators;

class PathGenerator implements PathGenerators
{
public function getPath(Media $media): string
{
    return $this->getBasePath($media).'/';
}

public function getPathForConversions(Media $media): string
{
    return $this->getBasePath($media).'/conversions/';
}

public function getPathForResponsiveImages(Media $media): string
{
    return $this->getBasePath($media).'/responsive-images/';
}

protected function getBasePath(Media $media): string
{
    //here im using trait to generate default path, e.g: path/mimes/avatar/media->id
    //its up to you to define folder structure, just make sure each folder
    //for conversions has unique name, or else it will be deleted
    $base_folder = $this->get_base_folder($media->mime_type);
    return "{$base_folder}/{$media->collection_name}/{$media->getKey()}";
}
}
```